# ¿Como configurar ng2-charts de manera horizontal?

Tags: angular, chart.js

Estoy trabajando con gráficos, pero he estado buscando para que sea de manera horizontal el grafico utilizando el tipo de gráfico `'bar'`, estoy utilizando  estas versiones:

```
"ng2-charts": "4.1.1",
"chart.js": "4.2.0",
```

A la hora de buscar información de como realizar el grafico llegue a esta configuración:

```
import { ChartConfiguration, ChartData, ChartEvent, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import DataLabelsPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective | undefined;

  public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: {
      x: { },
      y: {
        min: 10
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      datalabels: {
        display: false,
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end'
      }
    }
  };

  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';

  public barChartPlugins = [
    DataLabelsPlugin
  ];
```

Y para hacer la asignación de la información la hago de esta manera:
this.dashService.listFacturasComparativos().subscribe((data: any) => {
this.dataFacturas = data;

```
  let mappedData: MappedData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Presupuesto',
        data: [],
        type: 'line'
      },
      {
        label: 'Real',
        data: [],
        type: 'bar'
      }
    ]
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < this.dataFacturas.length; i++) {
    mappedData.labels.push(this.dataFacturas[i].ejercicio);
    mappedData.datasets[0].data.push(this.dataFacturas[i].p_PRESUPUESTO);
    mappedData.datasets[1].data.push(this.dataFacturas[i].p_REAL);
  }
  this.dataFormatFacturas = mappedData;
});
```

Todo esto utilizando las siguientes interfaces

```
interface Dataset {
  label: string;
  data: number[];
  type: string;
}

interface MappedData {
  labels: string[];
  datasets: Dataset[];
}
```

En el HTML, esta así:

```
<canvas baseChart class="chart"
        [data]="this.dataFormatFacturas"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
        [type]="barChartType">
</canvas>
```

Y muestra el gráfico, el verdadero problema viene cuando lo trato de colocar de manera horizontal, ya que investigando en este [link](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/706), o este [otro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-horizontalbar-stack?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) veo que configuran al menos en el segundo de esta manera:

```
public barChartType: ChartType = 'horizontalBar';
```

Pero para la versión que estoy trabajando no encuentra ese tipo de gráfico, trate de instalar las versiones estas:

```
"chart.js": "^2.7.3",
"ng2-charts": "2.0.0-beta.9"
```

Pero me marcan un montón de errores ya que utilizo angular 14 y no se como configurar lo ya que en otros links, me mandan a utilizar la siguiente manera:

```
options: {
        scales: {
            yAxis: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                barThickness: 10
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
```

Pero me marcan errores al utilizar  yAxis

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIÓN**

Investigando un poco mas, en algunos tutoriales que encontré ocupaban estas versiones:

```
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"ng2-charts": "^2.4.0",
```

a lo cual ocupe y si les causa algun problema al instalar ocupen `npm i --save chart.js@2.9.3 --legacy-peer-deps` y `npm i --save ng2-charts@2.4.0 --legacy-peer-deps` y se soluciona el inconveniente.

Para importar en app.module.ts hacen esto:

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
//En los imports solo esto
ChartsModule,
```

Para el html se usa esto:

```
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart
          [datasets]="barChartData"
          [labels]="barChartLabels"
          [options]="barChartOptions"
          [colors]="barChartColors"
          [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
          [legend]="barChartLegend"
          [chartType]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Y en el typeScript usan esto:

```
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Label, Color } from 'ng2-charts';
//....
 public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        },
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false,
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        },
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false,
        },
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
    }
  };

  public barChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: ["#ffffb2", "#fecc5c", "#fd8d3c", "#e31a1c"],
      borderColor: ['rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: ["#f6eff7", "#bdc9e1", "#67a9cf", "#02818a"],
      borderColor: ['rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']
    }
  ];
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2006'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'horizontalBar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [[65, 59], [80, 81], [56, 55]], label: 'Series A', borderWidth: 0},
    { data: [[28, 48], [40, 19], [86, 27]], label: 'Series B', borderWidth: 0 }
  ];
```